# Transform an attoparsec parser into a parser which fails if the number of bytes it consumes is not of a certain length

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

Say I have an attoparsec parser, `x`.

I am looking to create a function `f :: Int -> Parser a -> Parser a`, such that if `y = f n x`, then:

- `y` fails if `x` fails
- `y` fails if `x` succeeds and `x` does not consume `n` bytes
- `y` succeeds otherwise

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [match](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v:match) to implement it:

```
f n x = do
    (bs, res) <- match x
    guard (BS.length bs >= n)
    return res
```

You should check that this interacts with `(<|>)` in an acceptable way before putting it to heavy use.

Comment: In `binary` this function is packaged as `isolate`.  Perhaps it is more sensible there since `binary` tracks the number of bytes consumed, but it strikes me as a good addition to the attoparsec API (in terms of tokens, not bytes, so Text would not be counting bytes for example).